# Concatenating NULL+string on isNull

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was testing the `isNull` function, when I found out that if you concatenate NULL plus string, like this for example:

```
SELECT isNull(NULL+'123456','I am a flag')
```

The result is neither '1234' or 'I am a flag', it is 'I am a' instead.
The length of the result depends on the length of the concatenated string.

I would like to know the cause for this.

Comment: I you concatenate an unknown string with a known string, what do you expect to get?  a known or an unknown string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncation issue with ISNULL function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39544764/1260204)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ISNULL` returns the datatype of the first expression.

In your query you have `NULL+'123456'`, which is a `varchar(6)` and `'I am a flag'`, which is a `varchar(11)`. `NULL + {expression} = NULL` so the second parameter is returned and implicitly cast to a `varchar(6)`, resulting in `'I am a'` (the first 6 characters of the second expression).

Answer (score 4):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(NULL + '123456', 'I am a flag')
```

`ISNULL()` strictly uses the type of the first argument.  `COALESCE()` is more lenient, basically looking at the types of all arguments to ascertain the final type.  Plus, `COALESCE()` is standard SQL.